# Javascript string index

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on some javascript  on a website that helps companies see how their campaigns are doing on one collective screen. I am using an if statement to help separate some of the information but the when I go to check the code it says

> String index out of range -1

Here is the sample code:

```
var place = {Media Buy Name};

if(place.indexof("Prospecting")){
    return "Prospecting";
}
else if(place.indexof("AudienceTargeting")){
    return "AudienceTargeting";
}
else if(place.indexof("Retargeting")){
    return "Retargeting";
}
else{
    return "Other";
}
```

Comment: I dont get your definition of `place`, if it should be a string you need `"`s dont you?

Comment: What is `place` supposed to be? `{Media Buy Name};` is invalid JS syntax

Answer (score 4):

1) Javascript is case-sensitive. So `indexof` is not the same as `indexOf`.

2) Your `place` variable is an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals), so it has no methods except [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)'s ones unless you define a method manually yourself. Another option is making your variable an instance of `Array` or `String` which have `indexOf` method ([1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)).

So you have to either make your `place` variable  an instance of `Array`/`String` or define `indexOf` method manually within `place` object. Then your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

For if or else if condition indexOf function return int value so you have to compare it with.
If string found then return its index else return -1.
Check the following link:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

```
var place = 'Prospecting'; // Can by dynamic

if(place.indexOf('Prospecting') > -1){
    return 'Prospecting';
}
else if(place.indexOf('AudienceTargeting') > -1){
    return 'AudienceTargeting';
}
else if(place.indexOf('Retargeting') > -1){
    return 'Retargeting';
}
else{
    return 'Other';
}
```

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools. Use sites like [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), instead. The information on w3schools is often minimal or incomplete.

Comment: Thanks very much you your help